# Python - Run function every n second while true

Tags: python, time, while-loop, sleep

I read my way through a lot of posts but couldn't find a solution for an else condition working.
My loop sadly never stops. It seems like it's not repeatedly checking if *project.IsInProgress() = True*

I want to check all let's say every two seconds if my statement is still True, if it's no longer True I want to break the repetition and execute a print statement.

I guess the problem is that it's not running the function ever two seconds. But I don't know how to approach this.

```
check_status = project.IsInProgress()

while check_status:
    print('Render in progress..')
    time.sleep(2)
else: 
    print('Render is finished')
```

Comment: What returns IsInProgress? A boolean?

Comment: Yeah, the process returns a boolean, it seems like attaching it to a variable caused the boolean to not refresh.
I had a lot of variables assigned as I'm getting everything from an API. I'm now running all functions in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while project.IsInProgress():
    print('Render in progress..')
    time.sleep(2)
print('Render is finished')
```

Or if you prefer:

```
check_status = project.IsInProgress()
while check_status:
    print('Render in progress..')
    time.sleep(2)
    check_status = project.IsInProgress()
print('Render is finished')
```

Comment: I had to put all functions in each other to make it work. Thanks a lot. `GetManager().GetProject().IsRenderingInProgress():`

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks the in-progress only once in the beginning of the code and if it's True, the loop will last forever.
In order to check the status for each iteration , try:

```
while project.IsInProgress() :
    print('Render in progress..')
    time.sleep(2)
else: 
    print('Render is finished')
```